# Why does changing stepper value cause code to crash in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, uistepper

I am attempting to create an app in Xcode. I have added a stepper and a text box, and added outlets to the ViewController for these. When making an action to capture the change in stepper value, my code crashes upon clicking the stepper if I include any code at all in my changing value function.

Here is my ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        let newVal = Int(sender.value).description
        self.valueLabel.text = String(newVal)
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var generate: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

It says my main thread sends signal SIGABRT in the AppDelegate file, which I have not modified:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

This is the console output:

```
2019-12-18 00:16:00.234618-0600 core[95979:16142343] -[NSLayoutConstraint setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002c202d0
2019-12-18 00:16:00.240568-0600 core[95979:16142343] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSLayoutConstraint setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002c202d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4f02e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b97b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c6ff94 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c53dac ___forwarding___ + 1436
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c55f38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   core                                0x000000010c9fd5f3 $s4core14ViewControllerC19stepperValueChangedyySo9UIStepperCF + 643
    6   core                                0x000000010c9fd714 $s4core14ViewControllerC19stepperValueChangedyySo9UIStepperCFTo + 68
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47850dfa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4722ac22 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4722af6c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 398
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47be4a72 -[UIStepperHorizontalVisualElement _updateCount:] + 376
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47be473f -[UIStepperHorizontalVisualElement endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:] + 33
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47258372 -[UIStepper endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:] + 95
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47229e95 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 427
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4788bc1d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2604
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4788d524 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4596
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47868427 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff478e987e __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 6847
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff478ec344 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5980
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb2221 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb214c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb1924 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bac62f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23babe16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38438bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4784fb48 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    26  core                                0x000000010c9ff63b main + 75
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff51a1dc25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: check also all outlets properly connected with storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick look in debug console and I found something wrong. it's related to constraints, You are trying to set text in **NSLayoutConstraint**, Which is logically incorrect. Because NSLayoutConstraint doesn't have any property to set text.

Please review your code once and find out where you are trying to do like **[NSLayoutConstraint setText:]** or you can share your code with me, I can have a look on your code and fix it for you.